# Pronomen bei "etwas bei sich haben"

Tags: personal-pronoun

Ich verstehe folgenden Sachverhalt nicht. Folgende Sätze sind m.E. richtig:

> Ich habe Schokolade bei **mir**.
>
> Du hast Schokolade bei **dir**.
>
> Er/sie hat Schokolade bei **sich**.

Das fett markierte Wort entspricht also dem Dativ des [Reflexivpronomens](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/pronomen/reflexivpronomen)

Nun sagte aber die kleine Tochter eines Freundes:

> Sie hat Schokolade bei **ihr**.

wobei "ihr" hier dem Dativ des [Personalpronomens](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/pronomen/personalpronomen) entsprechen sollte. "mir" und "dir kann aber laut der Tabelle auch Dativ des Personalpronomens sein.

**Meine Frage:**

Ist eine der beiden Formen "bei ihr/ihm habe" und "bei sich haben" falsch? Oder ist beides in Ordnung und die Pronomen der 1. und 2. Person sind zufälligerweise gleich in beiden Fällen?

**Meine Vermutung:**

Beides ist korrekt, aber "Sie hat Schokolade bei ihr" ist nicht eindeutig und "sie" und "ihr" könnten sich auch auf zwei verschiedene Personen beziehen, "bei sich" ist eindeutig.

Da "bei mir" und "bei dir" eindeutig ist, stellt sich die Frage hier nicht bzw. es ist automatisch reflexiv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> - Sie hat Schokolade bei sich.
> - Sie hat Schokolade bei ihr.

Beide Sätze genügen den Regeln der deutschen Sprache und sind somit korrekt gebildet. Sie beschreiben jedoch unterschiedliche Sachverhalte, was ich verdeutlichen möchte, indem ich Kontext hinzufüge. Im Folgenden kennzeichnet **Fettdruck** den Besitzer der Schokolade.

#### Beispiel 1

> **Tina** ist bei der Oma. **Sie** hat Schokolade bei **sich**.
>   
>   (**Tina** ← **sie** ← **sich**)

Wo die Schokolade ist, lässt sich eindeutig beantworten: bei **Tina**. Das Reflexivpronomen **sich** bezieht sich auf das Subjekt des Satzes, d. h. auf das Reflexivpronomen **sie**. Das wiederum verweist auf das Subjekt des vorhergehenden Satzes, d. h. auf **Tina**.

#### Beispiel 2

> Tina ist bei der **Oma**. **Die** hat Schokolade bei **sich**.
>   
>   (**Oma** ← **die** ← **sich**)

Hier ist **Oma** Besitzerin der Schokolade. Das Reflexivpronomen **sich** bezieht sich wieder auf das Subjekt des Satzes, welches diesmal das Demonstrativpronomen **die** ist. Das verweist nun auf das letztgenannte Objekt des vorhergehenden Satzes, d. h. auf **Oma**.

#### Beispiel 3

> Tina ist bei der **Oma**. Sie hat Schokolade bei **ihr**.
>   
>   (**Oma** ← **ihr**)

Auch hier ist **Oma** die Besitzerin der Schokolade, denn das Personalpronomen **ihr** bezieht sich auf das letztgenannte Objekt des vorausgehenden Satzes, d. h. auf **Oma**

#### Ohne Kontext

In allen drei Beispielen sind die Bezüge also durch entsprechende Verwendung von *Reflexiv-*, *Personal-* und *Demonstrativpronomen* eindeutig festgelegt. Das gilt aber auch ohne den zusätzlichen Kontext. Wenn wir den Satz

> Sie hat Schokolade bei **ihr**.

aus Beispiel 3 herausgreifen, besagt er immer noch, dass das Subjekt des Satzes, *sie*, bei jemand anderem, nämlich *ihr*, Schokolade habe. Ob *sie* und *ihr* durch irgendeinen Kontext näher bestimmt werden können oder nicht, ist irrelevant.

#### Schlussfolgerung

Sprachlich sind beide Sätze korrekt, aber es gibt einen inhaltlichen Unterschied. Die Frage ist also, ob die Tochter Ihres Freundes auch gesagt hat, was sie meint. Ohne weitere Informationen lässt sich das nicht beantworten.

Comment: Ich hätte jetzt gesagt, dass der Satz mit "bei ihr" eben nicht eindeutig ist und das "ihr" sich sowohhl auf "Oma" als auch auf "Tina" beziehen könnte. Hast du eine Quelle für deine Behauptung? Ich will's eben genau wissen ;)

Comment: Kleine Anmerkung: "sich" ist nicht Relativpronomen, sondern Reflexivpronomen

Comment: Der Satz "Sie hat Schokolade bei ihr" ist nur dann korrekt, wenn "ihr" als Personalpronomen verwendet wird. Es bedarf also mehr Kontext um das zu beurteilen. Aus dem geschilderten Beispiel ist davon auszugehen, dass das Kind sagen will, dass die mit "sie" benannte Person Schokolade bei sich hat und dann ist es das Reflexivpronomen und somit ist "ihr" in diesem Fall falsch. Um zu ermitteln ob das Kind sich hier falsch oder richtig ausdrückt, könnte man nachfragen wer die Schokolade hat :-)

Comment: Sorry, aber für mich klingt "hat Schokolade bei ihr" einfach nicht nach einem korrekten deutschen Satz. Ich verstehe auch nicht, was das bedeuten soll.

Comment: @IQV Das ist ja auch Teil meiner Frage. Wenn du gute Quellen dafür hast, dass es nicht korrekt ist, mach doch eine Antwort draus :)

Comment: @Sentry: Würdest du denn sagen, dass auch ein Satz wie »Tina ist bei ihrer Oma und kämmt sie« nicht eindeutig ist? Nach meinem Sprachgefühl _muss_ man das Reflexiv- statt des Personalpronomens verwenden, wenn man sich auf das Subjekt bezieht, deshalb ist für mich in Stefans Beispiel »bei ihr« definitiv die Oma.

Comment: @DonHolgo Nein, das wäre für mich eindeutig. Guter Punkt. Aber hälst du das Reflexivpronomen in meinen Beispielen ebenfalls für notwendig?

Comment: @Sentry: Wenn's dieselbe »sie« ist, ja – ich sehe das genau wie Björn.

Comment: @IQV: Wenn ich bei Dir zu Besuch bin und Schokolade dort einen Gegenstand (z.B. Schokolade) dort lasse (vergesse oder bewusst deponiere), dann habe **ich** Schokolade **bei Dir**. In diesem Sinn kann eben auch "sie hat Schokolade bei ihr" ein korrekter Satz sein, das einzige Problem wäre, dass "sie" und "ihr" sich auf verschiedene Personen beziehen, ein Fall, bei dem man der Eindeutigkeit zuliebe eine der beiden Personen konkret benennen sollte. Wenn es ein Opa ist, wäre "sie hat Schokolade bei ihm" unproblematisch.